# check wp_login into a plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I'm writting a plugin for save the users in a table, i use this code:

```
function crear_bd_empleados() {
    global $wpdb;   
    $tabla_empleado = $wpdb->prefix.'myUser';       
    global $current_user;
    wp_get_current_user(); 
    $usuario = $current_user->user_login;
    $alias = $current_user->display_name;
    $nombre = $current_user->user_firstname.$current_user->user_lastname;
    $correo = $current_user->user_email;

    if (is_user_logged_in()){       
        $wpdb->insert( 
            $tabla_empleado, 
            array( 
                'usuario' => $usuario, 
                'alias' => $alias, 
                'nombre' => $nombre, 
                'correo' => $correo,                
            ) 
        );      
    }   
}
```

When i use `register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'crear_bd_empleados' );` it works fine, but i need register users when they log in the page and `add_action('wp_login', 'crear_bd_empleados');` is not working. How can i do it? Thx!

Comment: Why do you create another table to store the same data that is already stored in wp user table? It seems totally unnecessary to me, plus you lose the ability to use `WP_User_Query` class.

Comment: I'm trying clone data just for know how to do it, and i know this is useless, but i need to know how to check when user log-in into my plugin development.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you get user data in global $current_user variable only when a user is online or in other words, this is the data of currently logged user.

I think the problem is not with the hook or data, but with your insert code. It should be like this:

```
// You get two parameters, 2nd param is the user object
function crear_bd_empleados( $user_login, $user ) {
    global $wpdb;   
    $tabla_empleado = $wpdb->prefix.'myUser';       
    $current_user = $user;
    $usuario = $current_user->user_login;
        $alias = $current_user->display_name;
        $nombre = $current_user->user_firstname.$current_user->user_lastname;
        $correo = $current_user->user_email;

        $wpdb->insert( 
            $tabla_empleado, 
            array( 
                'usuario' => $usuario, 
                'alias' => $alias, 
                'nombre' => $nombre, 
                'correo' => $correo,                
            ),
            // You need to provide insert value types, %s = string in this case
            array('%s','%s','%s','%s')
        );     

}
// Register for wp_login with 2 params and priority = 10
add_action('wp_login', 'crear_bd_empleados', 10, 2);
```

As per the wiki: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login At wp_login hook, a user is logged in.

EDIT: wp_login sends two parameters, you can use 2nd parameter to get user data, no need to query again.

Comment: That's work fine! Thx a lot! you save my day

Comment: You're welcome, please accept the answer.